# Excel Conditional Formatting - creating an Office script

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, excel-addins, office-scripts

I have a small number of conditional formatting rules shown in the image below.

Formatting Rules Screenshot

[image: 1]

I have 4 conditional formatting rules in Excel but i'd like to automate them using Typescript.

What i'm having trouble with is format the colour of a row using Typescript , based on two cells in the row.

eg, If column $B1 contains "Y(UP)KZR" and column $G1 contains "DN to UP" then highlight that row.

I can then duplicate the code for the three other rules i'm looking to automate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure you want to apply the condtional format to all cells on worksheet?

Comment: Thanks. No, it’s only those two columns I’m really interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `getCustom().getRule().setFormula()` to setup CF formula
- `getAddress()` returns a reference with the sheet name. Transformation is needed for the CF formula.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // the used cells range
    // let selectedRange = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getUsedRange();
    // all cells
    let selectedRange = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange();
    let positiveChange = selectedRange.addConditionalFormat(ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.custom);
    // modify the filling color as needed
    positiveChange.getCustom().getFormat().getFill().setColor("lightgreen");
    const cellB = "$" + selectedRange.getCell(0, 1).getAddress().split("!")[1];
    const cellG = "$" + selectedRange.getCell(0, 6).getAddress().split("!")[1];
    const cfFormual = `=AND(${cellB}="Y(UP)KZR",${cellG}="DN to UP")`;
    positiveChange.getCustom().getRule().setFormula(cfFormual);
}
```